# Which speed hacks do I need to use to get Speedhax?

Tags: the-secret-world

There's an achievement called **Speedhax** that requires that you run across the **Dacian Span** in under 30 seconds.

Using the max rank of Sprint, I clocked myself at about 45 seconds to cross the span.

What abilities or items do I need to achieve a 33% increase in my time across the bridge?

Comment: Not that far yet, but this thread offers several options: http://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?p=1286523

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use these abilities;

- Rapid Getaway
- Speed Freak
- Flicker

You are better off using melee consumers (as you start with 5/5 melee resources, in contrast to another resources for pistols, for example) to trigger Rapid Getaway, preferably one that is instant cast so you can spam sprint immediately after.

- Start towards the starting line and trigger Rapid Getaway
- As you pass the start line trigger Speed Freak and then get sprint up as soon as possible
- Keep running toward the finish line with just sprint
- Use Flicker at the last second to get you over the finish line.

Without using Flicker at the last second you won't make it, recasting anything during the run will take you out of sprint, and will slow you down.